# Convert TextBox string to parameters

Tags: vb.net, command

How would I convert a string from a textbox to multiple parameters/arguments and store them in an array?

For example, if I was to write a command in the text box saying

> "setPosition label1 100 200"

then this would convert this into 4 different things:

- The "setPosition" part would be "command label" and then after that,
- they are different arguments that could be accessed though the array index.

So I could then do something like:

```
dim control as control = Me.Controls(argument(0))
control.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(argument(1), argument(2))
```

How do I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand right, but vb.net uses `()` to reference array indexes. Use [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to separate the arguments:

```
textbox1.Text = "setPosition label1 100 200"
Dim argument() as String = textbox1.Text.Split(" ")
Dim control as control = Me.Controls(argument(1))
control.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(argument(2), argument(3))
```

Comment: Your three indexes should be +1, right? (1, 2 and 3.)

Comment: @basher yea sorry, I've been doing java recently so I a little got confused. It's changed now

Comment: @clweeks Well they way i thought of doing this when i was writing it was different and would have been just 0, 1 and 2 but iv thought over and +1 works best